# ResourceExhaustedError only when fine-tuning a EfficientNetV2L in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am doing a multiclass image classification and this code is working fine, when I put `base_model.trainable = False`:

```
file_paths = train['image'].values  # train is a pd.DataFrame
labels = train['label'].values

valfile_paths = val['image'].values
vallabels = val['label'].values

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_paths, labels))
ds_val = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valfile_paths, vallabels))

def read_image(image_file, label):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_file)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (300, 500))
    return image, label


def augment(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=0.5)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    
    return image, label


ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image).map(augment).batch(28)
ds_val = ds_val.map(read_image).batch(28)

base_model = EfficientNetV2L(input_shape = (300, 500, 3),
                             include_top = False,
                             weights = 'imagenet',
                             include_preprocessing = True)

base_model.trainable = False

x = base_model.output
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(6, activation = 'softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = x)

model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001),
              loss = losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

callback = [callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 2)]

history =  model.fit(ds_train, batch_size = 28, validation_data = ds_val, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks = callback)
```

After training the model for 8 epoch (early stopping), I want to fine tune it by setting training = True, But when I turn `base_model.trainable = True`,then it gives me `ResourceExhaustedError`:

```
base_model.trainable = True

model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001),
              loss = losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

callback = [callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 2)]
history =  model.fit(ds_train, batch_size = 16, validation_data = ds_val, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks = callback)
```

error:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-6bda2975dd16> in <module>
      1 callback = [callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 2)]
      2 
----> 3 history =  model.fit(ds_train, batch_size = 16, validation_data = ds_val, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks = callback)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model/block3b_project_conv/Conv2D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 149, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 690, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 787, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 748, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 543, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2854, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3057, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-56-6bda2975dd16>", line 3, in <module>
      history =  model.fit(ds_train, batch_size = 16, validation_data = ds_val, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, callbacks = callback)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 458, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 250, in call
      outputs = self.convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 225, in convolution_op
      return tf.nn.convolution(
Node: 'model/block3b_project_conv/Conv2D'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[96,384,1,1] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node model/block3b_project_conv/Conv2D}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_351566]
```

I tried setting `batch_size` = 1, but it is still not working. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [V2L](https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet_v2/#efficientnetv2l-function) is a large model (`479MB`) and so I think it's normal to face `ResourceExhaustedError`. It depends on your GPU, whether it can take it or not. So, the simple answer would be to use better accelerator. However, here are some common approach you can try, but it's not guaranteed.

0. Use smaller input / unfreeze not all layers but few, etc.
1. Enable `mixed_precision`.
2. Configure `JIT` compilation.
3. Set **memory growth** for physical device (GPU).
4. If possible, use `TPU` accelerator (freely available on kaggle and colab.)

```
tf.config.optimizer.set_jit(True) # (2)
keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16") # (1)

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
for pd in physical_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(pd, True) # (3)
```

To set up TPU, check this [code-example [device-section]](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/keras-rsna-breast-cancer-detection-training). It might be helpful.Also check this [ticket](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15239), see the **[Feature Request 1]** section. Here you can find a [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FePCsRdutXNyTCiMGuXdXaB8QDj453R0?usp=sharing), you can use it to find the optimal batch size for training.